# How to create lines from ordered groupbyed points in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, gis, geospatial

### Reproducible setup

I have an (example) BigQuery table, `project.table.geodata`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `project.table.geodata` AS (
  SELECT ST_GEOGPOINT(70., 12.) AS geometry, 'a' AS loc, 1 as timestamp
   UNION ALL
  SELECT ST_GEOGPOINT(70., 14.) AS geometry, 'a' AS loc, 2 as timestamp
   UNION ALL
  SELECT ST_GEOGPOINT(72., 14.) AS geometry, 'a' AS loc, 3 as timestamp
    UNION ALL
  SELECT ST_GEOGPOINT(55., 24.) AS geometry, 'b' AS loc, 4 as timestamp
    UNION ALL
  SELECT ST_GEOGPOINT(55., 26.) AS geometry, 'b' AS loc, 5 as timestamp
    UNION ALL
  SELECT ST_GEOGPOINT(57., 26.) AS geometry, 'b' AS loc, 8 as timestamp
)
```

Visualization:

[image]

---

### Wanted outcome

I would like to group together the points having the same `loc` and create a line from them, ordering them by increasing `timestamp`.

Manually creation of expected output:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `project.table.lines` AS (
  SELECT ST_GeogFromText('LINESTRING(70 12, 70 14, 72 14)') as line
    UNION ALL
  SELECT ST_GeogFromText('LINESTRING(55 24, 55 26, 57 26)') as line
)
```

looks like:

[image]

The lines have the `GEOGRAPHY` datatype.

---

### What I have tried

I think I should `GROUP BY` column `loc`, sort within each group by `timestamp`, and then create the linestring from the resulting arrays.

I came up with:

```
select st_makeline(array_agg(geometry)) as lines from `project.table.geodata` group by loc;
```

but this does not guarantee that the order of points is increasing with the value of their associated `timestamp` value within the line.

---

### Question

**What SQL query produces the desired output?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be close to the answer. Just adding `ORDER BY` clause in your `ARRAY_AGG` will work as you want.

```sql
WITH geodata AS (
  SELECT ST_GEOGPOINT(70., 12.) AS geometry, 'a' AS loc, 1 as timestamp
   UNION ALL
  SELECT ST_GEOGPOINT(70., 14.) AS geometry, 'a' AS loc, 2 as timestamp
   UNION ALL
  SELECT ST_GEOGPOINT(72., 14.) AS geometry, 'a' AS loc, 3 as timestamp
    UNION ALL
  SELECT ST_GEOGPOINT(55., 24.) AS geometry, 'b' AS loc, 4 as timestamp
    UNION ALL
  SELECT ST_GEOGPOINT(55., 26.) AS geometry, 'b' AS loc, 5 as timestamp
    UNION ALL
  SELECT ST_GEOGPOINT(57., 26.) AS geometry, 'b' AS loc, 8 as timestamp
)
SELECT ST_MAKELINE(ARRAY_AGG(geometry ORDER BY timestamp)) AS lines 
  FROM geodata GROUP BY loc;

output:
+---------------------------------+
|              lines              |
+---------------------------------+
| LINESTRING(70 12, 70 14, 72 14) |
| LINESTRING(55 24, 55 26, 57 26) |
+---------------------------------+
```